# Remove minus sign from number in django tmplate

Tags: django

In my template I have this:

```
{{ gainer.total_progression }}
```

Which produces -5664

I need 5664

I tried

```
{{ gainer.total_progression }}|slice:"1:"
```

but it won't remove the -.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code is wrong, it should be:
`{{ gainer.total_progression|slice:"1:" }}`

Also, you could use [cut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) instead of slice:
`{{ gainer.total_progression|cut:"-" }}`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not against installing separate library for this, you can use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters/0.1.2).

```
{{ gainer.total_progression|abs }}
```